# Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' Spring

Tags: java, spring

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Card {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String full_name;
    private String login;
    private int balance;

    public Card() {
    }

    public Card(String full_name, String login, int balance) {
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.login = login;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public Card(Long id, String full_name, String login, int balance) {
        this.id = id;
        this.full_name = full_name;
        this.login = login;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getFull_name() {
        return full_name;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        .........    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, Long>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT us.id, ...", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Card> findAll();
}
```

Service

```
public interface CardService {

    List<Card> findAll();
}
```

Impl

```
@Service
public class CardServiceImpl implements CardService {

    @Autowired
    private CardRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Card> findAll() {
        List<ECard> list = new ArrayList<>();       
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/card")
public class CardController {

    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;

    public @ResponseBody List<Card> getAllCards() {
        return cardService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/card", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Card> cardList() {
        return cardService.findAll();
    }
}
```

I built a service like this. It works great. But I would like to save the data it receives to an xlsx file. This file should be saved when the application starts. I wanted to add the Workbook library instead of the existing Controller class, or rather its contents.

Something like that:

```
public class SaveCards {


    public static void saveCards() throws IOException {
        CardServiceImpl cardService = new CardServiceImpl();
        saveExcel(cardService.findAll(), "fileName.xlsx");
    }

    private static void saveExcel(List<Card> list, String fileName) throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Cards");
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 6000);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 4000);

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        XSSFFont font = ((XSSFWorkbook) workbook).createFont();
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
        font.setBold(true);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        Cell headerCell = header.createCell(0);
        headerCell.setCellValue("full_name");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(1);
        headerCell.setCellValue("login");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        headerCell = header.createCell(2);
        headerCell.setCellValue("balance");
        headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setWrapText(true);

        int ix_row=2;
        for (Card card : list) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(ix_row);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getFull_name());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getLogin());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(eCard.getBalance());
            cell.setCellStyle(style);

            ix_row++;
        }

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

However, if I changed the Controller class to the SaveCards class, I got an error: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' Spring

Now, the following comes out: Started DemonewApplication in 11.253 seconds (JVM running for 11.882). And that's all, no action takes place, the data received by the select is not saved to the xlsx file.
What am I doing wrong?

I understand that the saveCards method in the SaveCards class has to be called somewhere, but I can't figure out where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner` to run your code at Spring Boot startup.

```
@Component
class SaveCardsStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner 
{
    @Autowired
    private SaveCards saveCards;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args)
    {
        saveCards.saveCards();
    }
}
```

And the `SaveCards` class has to be changed as follows:

```
@Component
public class SaveCards {
{
    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;
    
    public void saveCards() throws IOException {
        saveExcel(cardService.findAll(), "fileName.xlsx");
    }

    private void saveExcel(List<Card> list, String fileName) throws IOException {...}
}
```

Comment: I do not quite understand where I should register the code that you indicate?

Comment: Do you need to call `SaveCards.saveCards()` everytime the application starts? Or do you need to call it on a API call?

Comment: " ...need to call SaveCards.saveCards() everytime the application starts"

Comment: Then just add mentioned class just in your project. Spring will recognize it because of annotation `@Component` and extending `ApplicationRunner`

Comment: In general, for the future, I want to put Scheduler and MailSender there, so that the resulting xlsx file is sent at a certain time by mail

Comment: When you change to Scheduler you can just drop `extend ApplicationRunner` and annotate the run method (remove args) with `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)` (see here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Again I cannot understand))
If I add "extend" to the main class, I get an error (Class 'DemonewApplication' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'run (ApplicationArguments)' in 'ApplicationRunner'
No interface expected here), same if I add this to another class

Comment: No, just copy the code and create a new class named `SaveCardsStartupRunner` in your project.

Comment: as you said, I created a separate class, but if I put "extends" - it writes to me - "No interface expected here. Change extends to implements", if I change to "implements" I get an error - "java.lang. IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner "

Comment: I started debugging. - "Class has no fields"

Comment: You are right it should be `implements`(hint: an interface can be implemented, a class can be extended).
Updated my code

Comment: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-19 14:17:54.065 ERROR 16308 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner

Comment: Is there any further error, why execution failed?

Comment: I started debugging. - "Class has no fields"

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Also debug says repository = null

Comment: Maybe you should learn more about Spring / Dependency Injection / Autowiring beans. Convert your class `SaveCards` into a injectable bean (not static) and inject `CardService` via `@Autowire` (good starting point: https://springframework.guru/dependency-injection-example-using-spring/)

Comment: In the SaveCards class, I wrote a private CardService cardService; further method: "@Autowired public void saveCards (CardService cardService)"

Comment: But now in the SaveCardsStartupRunner class, when SaveCards.saveCards is called, .saveCards is underlined in red (where it asks to make the saveCards method static)

Comment: I have updated my answer with more code. Try it that way.

Comment: I can't understand now. I did everything as you said. But now in the "SaveCardsStartupRunner" class, underlined in red .saveCards () says - Non-static method 'saveCards ()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Everything worked!)) Thank you very much for your help!